# SFML unable to create a loading bar using texture

Tags: c++, image, textures, loading, sfml

I am new to SFML and I am trying to create a loading bar, which can increase and decrease the loading value. Initially, the value starts from 0, increasing to 100, and decreasing to 0 again while doing the same thing infinitely.

I am trying to use a texture of an loading image to do so, as could be seen below.

[image]

The image is 410 x 130 and I plan to display 12.5% of the image on each time step, as well as cutting of 12.5% of it when the whole image has been displayed. I am doing something like this:

```
    sf::RectangleShape powerBar;
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("Power Bar.png"))
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to load texture";
    }
    powerBar.setPosition(powerBarPos);
    powerBar.setTexture(&texture);
    powerBar.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 41, 13));
```

However, I could not get what I intended to, as either the entire image is been displayed, or the one part of the image is being displayed in the wrong proportion.

May I know is there any way that I could work around to achieve what I intended? Thanks.

Comment: you should provide us this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this :

```
sf::Texture tex;
sf::Image image;
image.loadFromFile("Power Bar.png");
if (!tex.loadFromImage(image))
{
    // error...
    std::cout<<"Cannot load image"<<std::endl;
}
powerbar.setTexture(&tex);
```